# tsv file at path isn't found when running locally with Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Pulled a snippet out of my passion project because I cannot figure out why this file can't be found when running locally (Gatsby).  Why is that not a valid path? My tsv file is in the same directory as the calling file.  The tsv has 3 columns: time, stock, index

In the real project, useMarketData.js contains this snippet and the tsv and this file are both in src/

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "running locally"? `file:` protocol?

Comment: Gatsby develop and pulling up localhost

Comment: Your code should work from what I see. Do you point to `./src/script.js` in the HTML?

Comment: updated with another screenshot and additional info. yes its pointing to it

Comment: Pictures don't really help. You are getting a 404 error where the URL that causes the 404 does not contain "src".

Comment: i've tried './src/2019-01-02.tsv', '/src/2019-01-02.tsv', '.src/2019-01-02.tsv' and they all lead to the same error

Comment: What happens when you use the full path to the file?

Comment: that is not working for me either

Comment: Not sure how I can help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `tsv` file inside the `static` folder. Read the gatsby [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/static-folder/) for more details.